# Вывести данные из json на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пишу некий подбор.

Юзер нажал на блок с названием, через атрибут data-id я получил нажатый айди и отправил его аяксом на сервер. Там с помощью данного айди сделал выборку с базы и отправил все обратно в json формате.

Как мне обработать данные json, что бы вывести содержимое в html страницу. На php я бы просто обработал бы массив циклом и все вывел. Тут, понимаю, логика такая же. Но, к сожалению, js только учу и не совсем понимаю как.
Пробовал через `$('.content').html();` но получаю только последнюю итерацию цикла, понимаю, что каждой итерацией затираю предыдущие данные в `.content`.. Помогите советом

Comment: Получилось, добавляю нужную информацию - `$('.content').append('<div class="block-user" data-id="'+value['id']+'" data-name="'+value['name']+'">'+value['name']+'</div>');` Но как потом отследить клик по этому, созданому контейнеру? `$('.block-user').click( function()` не работает, понимаю, что из-за того, что контейнера не было на момент загрузки страницы. Но как тогда отследить клик?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $('.content').append(data[i]);
}
```